# Meteor client bundler throwing static-html error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-native, meteor-react

I'm trying to use meteor-client-bundler to package an existing meteor app for use on a new React Native project. The RN project is in a directory at the same level as the meteor app. When I try running meteor-client bundle --source=../myMeteorApp, I get the following error:

While processing files with static-html (for target web.browser):
client/main.html:12: Expected  or  tag

My client html file is pretty standard and compiles correctly with meteor. I suspect there is a conflict with packages, but am not really sure. Here is my main.html file for reference:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="My app">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
<!--   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png?v1" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
 -->
</head>
```

My meteor app is using react, but I don't think that should affect the meteor client bundler's ability to execute. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's on  ```client/main.html``` line 12?

Comment: Nothing, which was the confusing part. It actually appears to be an issue with the package. I opened an issue and requested to submit a PR. I'm waiting to confirm everything works correctly and see if that PR gets approved before closing/answering this question.